# External Connection String in App.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, app-config

I'm having trouble solving a problem with the connection string in EF, I want to separate connection string in other file.

I have an **connections.config** containing:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultContext" connectionString="myconnection" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And in my **App.config** I have:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>
```

But when I go to the model browser and try to update model, appears the update wizard to create new connection.
EF can't deal with this or I'm doing something wrong?

tnx

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to make a connection dinamically is doing manually like Code First.

Simply create the models and mappings manually.

```
DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext("the connection string you want");
var listUsers = db.UserProfiles.ToList();
```

And create a partial class on your "Models" implementing a DbContext interface.

```
public partial class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {

        public DatabaseContext(string connString)
            : base(connString)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
        }

        public DbSet<ASPStateTempApplication> ASPStateTempApplications { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ASPStateTempSession> ASPStateTempSessions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VisualizacoesLog> VisualizacoesLogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<webpages_Membership> webpages_Membership { get; set; }
        public DbSet<webpages_OAuthMembership> webpages_OAuthMembership { get; set; }
        public DbSet<webpages_Roles> webpages_Roles { get; set; }

    //Another Tables from database



        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ASPStateTempApplicationMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ASPStateTempSessionMap());    
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new sysdiagramMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserProfileMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new VisualizacoesLogMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new webpages_MembershipMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new webpages_OAuthMembershipMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new webpages_RolesMap());

            //Another mappings from database



        }
}
```

The link bellow has a good example of models and mapping.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/661053/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Map

Hope that helps. :)